# Equivalent to macro variable in R

Tags: r

My code:

cc$**obesity** <- factor(cc$**obesity**, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("*Obesity*", "Not *Obesity*"))
levels(cc$**obesity**)
label(cc$**obesity**)   <- "*Obesity*"

I want to change all the "obesity"(bold) to "cvd" and all the "Obesity"(Italic) to "CVD". How can I achieve this in R?

Thank you.

I know SAS has macro variable. But In R, I'm not sure we have this kind of thing?

Comment: R doesn't normally have italic or bold text in its variable names. Do you mean the literal string `*Obesity*`? Please [edit] your question and paste the output from `dput(head(cc))` into a [code block], ensuring that the sample you give us contains at least one of each to replace. It sounds like you want to rename some variables (`names(cc)[#] <- "cvd"` where `#` is the column numiber) and replace some others (`sub("\\*Obesity\\*", "*CVD*", cc$cvd)`).

Comment: @r2evans, I think they are asking how to programmatically change that code to `cc$cvd <- factor(cc$cvd, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("CVD", "Not CVD")) levels(cc$CVD) label(cc$csv) <- "CVD"`. In SAS the macro facility will make the substitutions before the code is evaluated. They're just using bold and italics to highlight the substitutions.

Comment: You want something to change the _expression_ above, or the contents of the `cc` frame?

Comment: @r2evans Yes. I mean exactly as LMc said.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a function of the IDE, not the language itself. Please [edit] your question to include what IDE (and its version and your OS) you're using.

Comment: As already mentioned, please add some data to your question using `dput`. You are thinking in SAS terms, but typically in R there are better ways to solve this problem than modifying the expression and then evaluating it. There is a lot of functionality in R for dealing with `list` objects, where you can more easily iterate over elements and modify them.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there is an easy way for for me to substitute variable names in R code. For example,something like: cc$var1 <- factor(cc$var1, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("var2", "Not var2")) levels(cc$var1) label(cc$var1) <- "var2". (var1=obesity, var2=Obesity)

Comment: If you are using RStudio, you can go to Edit > Replace and Find. From here you can make a copy of those lines, highlight the copied lines, select the "In selection" and "Match case" checkboxes, and then do a find and replace. Again I do not think this is the advisable way to solve your problem, but it is one way.